# Rails Runner or Rake task can't trigger Active Job job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, whenever, rails-activejob

I have setup a Rails 7 project running in Docker. Using the whenever gem (using cron) I tried to execute either

1. a rails runner task
2. a rake task

Both shall do the same thing: call a class method `WebpageChangeCheck.check_all` which itself calls a method of a model. Which then creates an Active Job job. But both fail in the final step to create the job:

```ruby
app/cron_jobs/webpage_change_check.rb:

class WebpageChangeCheck

  def self.check_all
    Webpage.all.each do |page|
      if page.checking_active
        page.check_for_change
      end
    end
  end

end



app/models/webpage.rb:

def check_for_change
  self.update(counter: self.counter += 1)
  UpdateOffersHashJob.perform_later(self)
end




update_offers_hash_job.rb:

class UpdateOffersHashJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  require 'nokogiri'
  require 'open-uri'
  require 'net/http'

  after_perform do |job|
    compare_hashes(job.arguments.first)
  end

  def perform(page)
    page.update(offers_hash_old: page.offers_hash_new)
    all_offers = ""
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(URI.open(page.url))
    doc.css(page.selector).each do |offer|
      all_offers += offer.to_s
    end
    page.update(offers_hash_new: all_offers.delete(" \t\r\n\ "))
  end

 private
  def compare_hashes(page)
    ...
  end
end
```

What works:

- calling the same class method from rails console creates the Active Job as expected. I get the following output:

```ruby
irb(main):002:0> WebpageChangeCheck.check_all
  Webpage Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "webpages".* FROM "webpages"
  Webpage Update All (3.9ms)  UPDATE "webpages" SET "counter" = COALESCE("counter", 0) + $1 WHERE "webpages"."id" = $2  [["counter", 1], ["id", 1]]
Enqueued UpdateOffersHashJob (Job ID: 707e164d-b8b9-407b-aa35-4b23c37b4f07) to Async(default) with arguments: #<GlobalID:0x00007f2e0b7c4878 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://my_rails_app/Webpage/1>>
=> 
[#<Webpage:0x00007f2e0b7bded8
  id: 1,
  title: "example.com",
  url: "https://www.example.com",
  user_id: 1,
  created_at: Wed, 18 Jan 2023 14:22:51.904097000 CET +01:00,
  updated_at: Fri, 20 Jan 2023 00:12:02.749748000 CET +01:00,
  interval: 1,
  checking_active: true,
  selector: ".headline_content",
  counter: 386>]
  Webpage Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "webpages".* FROM "webpages" WHERE "webpages"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Performing UpdateOffersHashJob (Job ID: 707e164d-b8b9-407b-aa35-4b23c37b4f07) from Async(default) enqueued at 2023-01-20T07:26:02Z with arguments: #<GlobalID:0x00007f2e092e1088 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://my_rails_app/Webpage/1>>
  TRANSACTION (0.2ms)  BEGIN
User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
irb(main):003:0>   TRANSACTION (1.0ms)  COMMIT
  TRANSACTION (0.4ms)  BEGIN
  Webpage Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "webpages".* FROM "webpages" WHERE "webpages"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Sim Create (1.4ms)  INSERT INTO "sims" ("to", "time", "api_response", "success", "webpage_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id"  [["to", 49123456789], ["time", nil], ["api_response", nil], ["success", nil], ["webpage_id", 1], ["created_at", "2023-01-20 07:26:03.108189"], ["updated_at", "2023-01-20 07:26:03.108189"]]
  TRANSACTION (3.5ms)  COMMIT
  TRANSACTION (0.4ms)  BEGIN
  Sim Update (1.0ms)  UPDATE "sims" SET "time" = $1, "api_response" = $2, "success" = $3, "updated_at" = $4 WHERE "sims"."id" = $5  [["time", "Fri, 20.01.23 - 08h26 03s"], ["api_response", "100\nVerbucht: 0\nPreis: 0.075\nGuthaben: 0.35\nText: ALERT\nSMS-Typ: direct\nFlash SMS: false\nEncoding: gsm\nGSM0338: true\nDebug: true"], ["success", true], ["updated_at", "2023-01-20 07:26:03.295980"], ["id", 22]]
  TRANSACTION (3.8ms)  COMMIT
Performed UpdateOffersHashJob (Job ID: 707e164d-b8b9-407b-aa35-4b23c37b4f07) from Async(default) in 585.89ms
```

What I see from bash (from rake or rails runner) the Active Job gets created but it will not perform:

```
root@f77855c949a8:/opt/app# rake debug check_all_pages
  Webpage Load (1.5ms)  SELECT "webpages".* FROM "webpages"
  ↳ app/cron_jobs/webpage_change_check.rb:4:in `check_all'
  Webpage Update All (2.9ms)  UPDATE "webpages" SET "counter" = COALESCE("counter", 0) + $1 WHERE "webpages"."id" = $2  [["counter", 1], ["id", 1]]
  ↳ app/models/webpage.rb:9:in `check_for_change'
[ActiveJob] Enqueued UpdateOffersHashJob (Job ID: f4495cb8-868f-4ed5-9f03-7f4407b5efa4) to Async(default) with arguments: #<GlobalID:0x00007fd55771ece0 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://my_rails_app/Webpage/1>>
root@f77855c949a8:/opt/app#
```

here you also go with the rake task:

```ruby
my_rails_app/lib/tasks/checker_task.rake:

  desc "checks all Webpages for changes. Called from cronjob."
  task check_all_pages: :environment do
    WebpageChangeCheck.check_all
  end
```

Conclusion:

- it seems like the environment loaded properly, including environment variables. I have access to my classes and models.
- nevertheless there seems to be a difference which prevents the Job from being performed.
- part of the problem might be there is not enough logging to debug it, so this could be improved as well!

Any ideas?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? You say that running this fails to create the job, but later you say that the job is created (*it reads the callback*) but the `perform` method isn't being called. It would help if you included the exact steps you're taking to attempt to run the job and the exact output you get from those steps. Separately, `check_for_change` has a race condition that can be resolved by using [`increment_counter`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/CounterCache/ClassMethods.html#method-i-increment_counter) instead.

Comment: Sure, let's try: running `WebpageChangeCheck.check_all` from rails console works. The same does not succeed neither when being run from bash with `rake <rake task calling WebpageChangeCheck.check_all>` nor `rails runner  WebpageChangeCheck.check_all`.  Same via the cronjob. It stops exactly at the perform method. This I found out by putting debugging messages or breakpoint in the code. I don't get any error message saying it tries to run the perform method, it is simply being ignored. Hopefully clearer now!? Thanks for the hint with the race condition!

Comment: Please don't try to elaborate on your question in comments. Updates go in your question. No, this is not any clearer. You're using words like "works" and "does not succeed" instead of showing **exactly** what the inputs and outputs are. Does "does not succeed" mean that you enqueue the job but it doesn't run or does it mean that it doesn't enqueue? **What** "stops exactly at the perform method"? Your question should say *I do <these exact steps> and I expect <this exact part of the chain> to show <this exact output> but instead <this exact part of the chain> shows <some other exact output>.*

Comment: Also include the code for method `page.checking_active` in question

Comment: Hey, sorry for being too Noob here, I try harder :) See updates in the question. The reason I did not include any outputs is cause part of the problem is that there is almost no logging when using rake or rails runner from bash. But I tried to add a logger and now at least there is the output that the job indeed gets submitted. Method `checking_active` is just a boolean in the db.

Answer (score 0):

You need to process your job queue in another process, e.g.

```
rake jobs:work
```

Comment: So you say I should put all the logic in one Active Job job? Then just call rake jobs:work from the cronjob/whenever? I just tried `rake jobs:work`, `rails jobs:work` or `bundle exec rake jobs:work` all of which ended in `Don't know how to build task 'jobs:work' ` Could you please explain a bit why this would solve it? Thanks!

Comment: I recommend reading https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html and I recommend setting up DelayedJob for the queue (it's the simplest)

Answer (score 0):

So, thanks to the help in the comments I realized I overlooked to install the delayed_job backend/processing queue incl. db table for Active Job cause I thought this comes with it. It is needed to enqueue and work off the jobs. Not suitable for large amounts of jobs but sufficient for my purpose.

Here is a complete guide:
https://axiomq.com/blog/deal-with-long-running-rails-tasks-with-delayed-job/

You can also check these docs:
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html
https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#active-job

Short version:
I added the `gem 'delayed_job_active_record'`
Add and execute

```ruby
bundle install

config/application.rb:
config.active_job.queue_adapter = :delayed_job

rails generate delayed_job:active_record
rails db:migrate
rails jobs:work
```

As mentioned, this is a seperate process that has to be run.

Question remains why the job performs when being run through rails console. Maybe it won't queue then but execute rightaway ..